# Каким будет метод ничья в игре крестики нолики

Tags: java, android

игра у меня все работает отлично, когда побеждает крестик, появляется alertdialog, в общем все работает кроме ничья, вот тут методы для победы

```
public void winnerx() {
    boolean finish = false;
    String s1 = btn1.getText().toString();
    String s2 = btn2.getText().toString();
    String s3 = btn3.getText().toString();
    String s4 = btn4.getText().toString();
    String s5 = btn5.getText().toString();
    String s6 = btn6.getText().toString();
    String s7 = btn7.getText().toString();
    String s8 = btn8.getText().toString();
    String s9 = btn9.getText().toString();

    if (s1.equals("X") && s2.equals("X") && s3.equals("X") || s1.equals("X") && s4.equals("X") && s7.equals("X") || s1.equals("X") && s5.equals("X") && s9.equals("X") ||
            s2.equals("X") && s5.equals("X") && s8.equals("X") ||
            s3.equals("X") && s2.equals("X") && s1.equals("X") || s3.equals("X") && s6.equals("X") && s9.equals("X") || s3.equals("X") && s5.equals("X") && s7.equals("X") ||
            s4.equals("X") && s5.equals("X") && s6.equals("X") || s7.equals("X") && s8.equals("X") && s9.equals("X")) {
        finish = true;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main4Activity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Winner - X").setMessage("Do you want to play again?").setCancelable(false).
                setPositiveButton("Play again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Main4Activity.this, Main4Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main4Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    if (finish) {
        btn1.setEnabled(false);
        btn2.setEnabled(false);
        btn3.setEnabled(false);
        btn4.setEnabled(false);
        btn5.setEnabled(false);
        btn6.setEnabled(false);
        btn7.setEnabled(false);
        btn8.setEnabled(false);
        btn9.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Вот это для нолика

```
 public void winnero() {
    boolean finish = false;
    String s1 = btn1.getText().toString();
    String s2 = btn2.getText().toString();
    String s3 = btn3.getText().toString();
    String s4 = btn4.getText().toString();
    String s5 = btn5.getText().toString();
    String s6 = btn6.getText().toString();
    String s7 = btn7.getText().toString();
    String s8 = btn8.getText().toString();
    String s9 = btn9.getText().toString();

    if (s1.equals("O") && s2.equals("O") && s3.equals("O") || s1.equals("O") && s4.equals("O") && s7.equals("O") || s1.equals("O") && s5.equals("O") && s9.equals("O") ||
            s2.equals("O") && s5.equals("O") && s8.equals("O") ||
            s3.equals("O") && s2.equals("O") && s1.equals("O") || s3.equals("O") && s6.equals("O") && s9.equals("O") || s3.equals("O") && s5.equals("O") && s7.equals("O") ||
            s4.equals("O") && s5.equals("O") && s6.equals("O") || s7.equals("O") && s8.equals("O") && s9.equals("O")) {
        finish = true;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main4Activity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Winner - O").setMessage("Do you want to play again?").setCancelable(false).
                setPositiveButton("Play again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Main4Activity.this, Main4Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main4Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    if (finish) {
        btn1.setEnabled(false);
        btn2.setEnabled(false);
        btn3.setEnabled(false);
        btn4.setEnabled(false);
        btn5.setEnabled(false);
        btn6.setEnabled(false);
        btn7.setEnabled(false);
        btn8.setEnabled(false);
        btn9.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Пробовал для ничьи этот метод, но не работает

```
public void draw(){

    if(btn1.isPressed() && btn2.isPressed() && btn3.isPressed() && btn4.isPressed() && btn5.isPressed() &&
            btn6.isPressed() && btn7.isPressed() && btn8.isPressed() && btn9.isPressed()){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main4Activity.this);
        builder.setTitle("DRAW").setMessage("Do you want to play again?").setCancelable(false).
                setPositiveButton("Play again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Main4Activity.this, Main4Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main4Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так (хотя я бы переписал вообще весь код так чтобы его понять было бы проще):

```
public void draw(){

    String s1 = btn1.getText().toString();
    String s2 = btn2.getText().toString();
    String s3 = btn3.getText().toString();
    String s4 = btn4.getText().toString();
    String s5 = btn5.getText().toString();
    String s6 = btn6.getText().toString();
    String s7 = btn7.getText().toString();
    String s8 = btn8.getText().toString();
    String s9 = btn9.getText().toString();

    if (!(s1.isEmpty() || s2.isEmpty() || s3.isEmpty() || s4.isEmpty() || s5.isEmpty() || s6.isEmpty() || s7.isEmpty() || s8.isEmpty() || s9.isEmpty())) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main4Activity.this);
        builder.setTitle("DRAW").setMessage("Do you want to play again?").setCancelable(false).
                setPositiveButton("Play again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Main4Activity.this, Main4Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main4Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ща это попробую и сообщу, спс

Comment: Спс все сработало))) не знаю, че было не то написано))

Comment: я не большой специалист в андроид, по подозреваю что isPressed не возвращал true в данном случае, а в коде выше мы использовали тот же алгоритм получения значения через строки, как и в других методах.

Answer (score 1):

Также как для крестика и нолика получайте текст с каждой кнопки, проверяйте, что не на одной из них текст не равен "" (или чему он равен по умолчанию), а потом проверяйте что ни крестик, ни нолик не выиграл.

Comment: Это не помогло, пробовал не получался, Думал если убрать текст сработает, но увы нет))

Comment: @hayk.mkrtchyan2017 что именно идёт не так?

Comment: сам не понимаю, условие пишу правильно но не работает